# how to grep out a particular line from a file

Tags: grep

How can I grep out a particular line from a file in a folder.

Basically I have a folder `/my/cool/folder/myfile.txt`

I know it has line: `I am cool lkasjdfaksldfj`

How can I grep on that file so the line starting with `I am cool ....` shows on the terminal?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
$ grep "^I am cool lkasjdfaksldfj" /my/cool/folder/myfile.txt
```

Also:

```
$ man grep
```

It'll do ya good.

Answer (score 0):

grep "^I am cool lkasjdfaksldfj" /my/cool/folder/myfile.txt

If you want to search in all files in a folder

grep "^I am cool lkasjdfaksldfj" /my/cool/folder/*

If you want the string to be searched anywhere and not necessarily the beginning of line

grep "I am cool lkasjdfaksldfj" /my/cool/folder/myfile.txt

Answer (score -3):

also

```
$ cat myfile | grep mytext
```

in order to output to the terminal

Comment: Useless use of `cat`.

Comment: Why limit yourself to a single process when you can use two?!?! ;)